# why timer count down irregularly?

Tags: swift, timer

I'm making a timer app for my parents, but it countdown irregularly sometimes...

[Count down too fast when set 10 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo28Y.gif)

Especially first count when started first and resumed like photos.

```
if timer == nil {
        self.timerTime = self.originalTime
        timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(flags: [], queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        timer?.schedule(deadline: .now() + 2, repeating: 1)
        timer?.setEventHandler(handler: {
            if self.timerTime > 0 {
                //timer run
                self.timerTime -= 1
                self.timeCal()
                self.playSound()
                print(self.timerTime)
            } else {
                //timer end
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.view.backgroundColor = .red
                    AudioServicesPlayAlertSoundWithCompletion(1304, nil)
                }
                self.timeCal()
                
                self.appStat = Stat.loopEnd
                self.timer?.cancel()
                self.timer = nil
            }
        })
    }
```

Here's my timer logic.
I'm using DispatchSourceTimer for convenience resume.

```
func updateLabel() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.minuteLabel.text = String(format: "%02d", self.minuteCount)
        self.secondLabel.text = String(format: "%02d", self.secondCount)
    }
}

func timeCal() {
    self.minuteCount = self.timerTime / 60
    self.secondCount = self.timerTime % 60
    updateLabel()
}
```

and here is another method used.

I already change timer's queue main to global but it same...

I think maybe this is why many samples use Timer class's scheduled timer.

It can solve if I change dispatchSourceTimer to Timer class?

If it correct, why this difference with between them?

Thanks to read my poor English.
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to invalidate the current running timer and make it nil when you update the duration from the Settings screen.

Let me know if there's any doubt.

Comment: that's right when if I run any timer before set timer.
but the first time has no current running timer. 